# Space in Git --commit-filter for GIT_AUTHOR_NAME

Tags: windows, git, github

I am attempting to rename all commits' authors in a local repository before uploading to GitHub, but I get an error if the name contains a space. The repository was not originally configured with a name and all commits are from the same user.

Here is the script I have been using:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="FirstName LastName";
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="FirstNameLastName@users.noreply.github.com";
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="FirstName LastName";
GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="FirstNameLastName@users.noreply.github.com";
git commit-tree "$@";' HEAD
```

And the error that results:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'LastName;
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=FirstNameLastName@users.noreply.github.com;
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=FirstName': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

I have attempted to resolve the issue by escaping the space with `\` however I have only been able to successfully run the script by removing the space, e.g. `FirstName LastName` becomes `FirstNameLastName`

Comment: Are you on Windows?  No *sane* shell behaves like that.  Windows... not so sane. :-)  I don't know the right way to deal this this, other than "install a sane shell and/or avoid Windows" (I use the latter method).

Comment: @torek I am using Windows! Although issues like this make me reconsider...

Comment: Seems to be a Windows issue. Script would not run properly in Powershell but works perfectly in Git Bash. Hmm... Macs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with Powershell on Windows. After switching to Git Bash the script ran correctly with the spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter "
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME='FirstName LastName';
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL='FirstNameLastName@users.noreply.github.com';
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME='FirstName LastName';
GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='FirstNameLastName@users.noreply.github.com';
git commit-tree ""$@"";" HEAD
```

I changed the " to ' and vice versa and added double quotes around $@

Comment: I had already tried this before posting the question, and it did not work. Thank you though.

Comment: Strange - I tried it on my Windows 10 machine and it worked.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: I just switched to Git Bash and it worked. Sounds like a Windows bug. Thanks for the suggestions though!

Comment: Worked in Windows 10 with PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

An additional solution which is working on powershell core:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]
    $name,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]
    $email
)
$command = @"
GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='$mail';
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL='$mail';
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME='$name';
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME='$name';
git commit-tree "$@";
"@

& git filter-branch -f --commit-filter $command head
```